# how to replace one part in url by using R

Tags: html, r, text-mining

Currently I have the website

http://www.amazon.com/Apple-generation-Tablet-processor-White/product-reviews/B0047DVWLW/ref=cm_cr_pr_btm_link_2?ie=UTF8&pageNumber=1&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending

I want to replace this part

pageNumber=1

to be replaced with a sequence of numbers such as 1,2,3,.....n

I know I need to use the `paste` function. But can do I locate this number and replace it?

Comment: If you solve your own problem, you should enter the solution as an answer, rather than appending it to your question. If you feel it's the best solution, there's nothing wrong with marking it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `parseQueryString` function from the `shiny` package or `parse_url` and `build_url` from `httr` package.

```
require(shiny)
testURL <- "<http://www.amazon.com/Apple-generation-Tablet-processor-White/product-reviews/B0047DVWLW/ref=cm_cr_pr_btm_link_2?ie=UTF8&pageNumber=1&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending>"
parseURL <- parseQueryString(testURL)
parseURL$pageNumber <- 4
newURL <- paste(names(parseURL), parseURL, sep = "=", collapse="&")

require(httr)
testURL <- "<http://www.amazon.com/Apple-generation-Tablet-processor-White/product-reviews/B0047DVWLW/ref=cm_cr_pr_btm_link_2?ie=UTF8&pageNumber=1&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending>"
parseURL <- parse_url(testURL)
parseURL$query$pageNumber <- 4
newURL <- build_url(parseURL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
# inputs
URL1 <- "...whatever...&pageNumber=1"
i <- 2

URL2 <- sub("pageNumber=1", paste0("pageNumber=", i), URL1)
```

or using a perl zero width regex:

```
URL2 <- sub("(?<=pageNumber=)1", i, URL1, perl = TRUE)
```

If we know that there is no 1 prior to `pageNumber`, as is the case here, then it simplifies to just:

```
URL2 <- sub(1, i, URL1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another very simple approach is to use `sprintf`:

```
sprintf('http://www.amazon.com/Apple-generation-Tablet-processor-White/product-reviews/B0047DVWLW/ref=cm_cr_pr_btm_link_2?ie=UTF8&pageNumber=%s&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending', 
        1:10)
```

In the above code, the `%s` in the string provided as the first argument is replaced by each element of the vector provided in the second argument, in turn.

See `?sprintf` for more details about this very handy string manipulation function.

Answer (score 0):

simplest approach would be splitting the string to

```
var part1 = " http://www.amazon.com/Apple-generation-Tablet-processor-White/product-reviews/B0047DVWLW/ref=cm_cr_pr_btm_link_2?ie=UTF8&pageNumber=";

var number =1;

var part2 = "&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending"

link = part1+number+part2
```

another approach would be to use `string.replace("pageNumber=1","pageNumber=2");`

and another option would be to use regex but im not good with that youll have to do some googling.

Comment: cuz i figured it by myself. and his or her idea is similar to me. i should look carefully.

Answer (score 0):

i figure it out now, the code is here.

```
listurl<-paste("http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047DVWLW",1:218)
ipadlisturl<-paste(listurl,"&showViewpoints=0&sortBy=bySubmissionDateDescending")
```